# Trying to figure out the mathematics behind the classical superhero lift-by-the neck

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, biophysics

I recently got into a debate about the classical villain or hero move of lifting an adversary by the neck. We've all seen the one-arm or even two-arm lift and i made the case that even two arms against a wall would be a close-to impossible feat by any human but of course the relative strength and weight has a say in this. That is why im posting this question here.

**How would one do the math, taking into account joints and levers (shoulder, elbow, upper arm and forearm) the relative angle/height and weight plus the wall(?), on the two-arm against a wall lift**

*(the one-arm would be cool as well, but lets look at the "easy one" from a human capability point of view.)*

I would guess most of the torque needs to be generated by the shoulders just like a front delt raise of sorts to even lift someone maybe with a lot of static force by biceps and hands.

Please feel free to add in details i have overlooked.

**Thank you**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We are pretty startling creatures.

I don't have any experience lifting people up by the neck.  Those who do tend not to spend much time answering stack exchange questions.  And so, I go to videos.

This video shows a [front raise](https://youtu.be/t-h0T3dE8t4?t=320) workout by bodybuilder Seth Feroce.  I can't see the numbers on the weights very well, but based on the numbers on the weights in his [instructional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALNyDCkW9y8), I think he's working out with 40-50 pound weights.  And mind you, he's doing this for "fun" and doing many many reps.  I think its safe to assume that he could do much more if he was doing a single rep.

One also has to consider the psychology of the situation.  In scenes like the picture you posted, the villain is angry.  The human body actually holds back a *lot*, to avoid injuring itself.  We have stress sensors in our tendons that can actually shut off our muscles if they come under too much strain.  However, these sensors can be turned off by the brain.  When you hear stories of mothers lifting a car, that's what can be done by the human body when it really needs to.  The price is that you tear muscles and tendons and may need weeks of rehabilitation afterwards (or you may never be the same at all).

And, of course, we have to consider the strength of the hand required to lift a person.  A lot depends on hand shapes, but between [bodybuilders](https://youtu.be/7ArJeC7oagw?t=42), [climbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84OkzOIfphg), and [gymnasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdjWgw98EeI) there is a lot of evidence to suggest the structure of the hand can hold a bodyweight without that much trouble.

Now, you ask for math.  You aren't going to get any from me.  It turns out the biomechanics of the human body are astonishingly complicated compared to the nice easy diagrams of levers and pulleys we see in textbook problems.  It keeps surprising me every time.  Some of the behaviors, like force-velocity curves of our muscles are rooted in CFD modeling of the liquid inside our muscle cells, and nearly all of our muscles and bones in our body are in some [tensegrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensegrity) like layout, which are quite strong and flexible and notoriously hard to calculate equations of motion for.

A major example is how you actually lift someone in such an awkward angle.  Sure, you can do a nice easy textbook physics problem by doing a front lift.  But if you really want someone in the air, that's not how you do it.  Instead, you bend your knees a little, get under them, and then rise up.  Why does this work better?  A peculiarity of our muscles, our muscles are actually stronger in isometric contraction than in concentric contraction.  In fact, they are about [3 times stronger](http://muscle.ucsd.edu/musintro/props.shtml), which means that if you can do a front-press of 70 pounds, you can hold your position against a load of about 210 pounds.  Thus, to get more apparent strength, you bend at your knees a little to make it easier to get your arm into position, before lifting them with your legs rather than your biceps or delts.

The real limiting factor of this kind of lift is that the person you are lifting is squirming.  I think much of the terror in these scenes is how the intimidating posture of the villain causes the good guy to become calm and complicit, afraid to act out for fear that the villain will snap their neck.  Lifting a squirming body is *much* harder than lifting dead weight.

The one certain physics requirement is that the center of their combined bodies must be over the villain's foot.  If the villain does not lean back a little or shove the good guy up against a wall, then the villain will simply tip over and there's nothing that can be done about it.  (Unless you have access to the force, in which case you write your own physics textbooks)

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following to strengthen your argument. Consider the free-body diagram of a forklift. If the center of the 2-body mass is not supported directly under the lifter then the system will tip. You often do not see the villain repositioning his footing so that at least one foot is directly under the center of mass. It doesn't matter how strong any of his muscles are, the two-body system would then tip over.